# Unable to turn bluetooth on, Ubuntu 22.04 with Intel WiFi 6 AX200 card

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, bluetooth, 22.04

So Ive dual booted ubuntu with Windows 10 in different drives, and everything is working well (including wifi), apart from bluetooth, which says "No bluetooth found" in the settings. What can I do to troubleshoot the problem?

Note: Ive already disabled both secure and fast boot.

```
tomas@TOMAS:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i Blue
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200NGW [8086:0084]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1532:0084 Razer USA, Ltd RZ01-0321 Gaming Mouse [DeathAdder V2]
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c31b Logitech, Inc. Compact Keyboard K300
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:0892 Logitech, Inc. C920 HD Pro Webcam
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 048d:5702 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1e71:2007 NZXT NZXT USB Device
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 445a:1424 DZTECH DZ65RGBV3
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
```

EDIT2: It's working now, 2 days after installing this version of ubuntu.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i Blue` terminal command.

Comment: thank you, edited the question

Comment: Also please add output of `sudo dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: no output whit that command

Comment: You probably made a typo. Copy and paste the command.

Comment: I did that before and right now to confirm (even with extra spaces), but the command still gives me no output...